# Get Alert Notification when azure function returns code 200

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-alerts

I want to get notification when my azure function returns status 200. I have set up Alert and I am part of Action group that's supposed to receive alert.

Issue is, I am not getting alert. I checked Monitoring Graph for given signal aka HTTP 2XX,
There also I see nothing.

I send this from code

```
            return func.HttpResponse(
                f"Total time took {time.time()-st}",
                status_code=200
            )
```

And My Azure portal looks like this
[azure portal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmYs1.png)

Comment: Why would you need alert when success status code is returned, just curious.

Comment: Also, typical latency is expected, if your alert definition has frequency of 1 min, then you will get notified in under 5 mins as per official docs.

Comment: Have you checked your function app's App Insight charts , were there successful executions?

Comment: @anand-sowmithiran There's a requirement where a success alert is required. Right now, Email is not receiving at all,I checked Logs, Things seem alright to me. If you were to do this, What different would you do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get notification when my azure function returns status 200.
> I have set up Alert and I am part of Action group that's supposed to
> receive alert.

I tried to create an notification alert for my function . When  run my function if it returns `200 OK` ,then it send me an mail notification of it.

Here are steps:

- **Created an function with http trigger and create alert** from function app > Alert >Create alert and  add condition and action group and email /phone details to receive an notification .

[image]

Here is the configurations based on your requirement

[image]

- Settings inside alert in action added **function** :

[image]

- Run my function app and returned 200 status:

[image]

Here is the email notifications:

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer this [Blog](http://www.mattruma.com/adventures-with-azure-functions-create-an-alert-from-app-insight-to-send-an-email-notification/)  & [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log) .

Comment: Hello @AlmightyHeathcliff , Any update !!  If the provided solution worked ,could you please accept the answer so as it would be beneficial for other community members and to the question shall stand answered.

Comment: Hey, Thanks. I didn't get chance to open SO, Thanks a lot for answering. Let me apply your solution, I'll do the needful. Thanks again

Comment: Hello @AlmightyHeathcliff , Did the solution worked ? Any update .Please let me know :) Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, Alert was Triggered but Email wasn't received, I'm looking into that. At least now I can see count in graph for statuscode 200

Comment: Please make sure that you have add action type as Function . In my case i received email in 5 min. . Also please refer the Doc. that shared in answer.